# Rstudio 'rerun with debug'

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

My Rstudio used to have a click for 'Rerun with debug' when an error occurs. Like in the picture below:
[image]

And I got a new version 0.99.896 today, then it disappeared. What can I do to get it back? Any commands do the same thing?

Comment: debug => on error options

Comment: @phiver tried that. No matter what I selected, it only returned error message

Comment: What is the code that you are running? I believe RStudio only shows the error inspector when you have a stack trace with at least two call frames available; you won't see it for 'top-level' errors.

Comment: @KevinUshey I  just used some toy functions that I wrote, very simple.  I also tried 'second-level' error, that click still didn't show up.

Comment: Did you find out why ? I have the same issue and think of a bug of RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re diagnosing a specific error, you can have RStudio halt execution at the point where the error is raised. To do this, go to Debug -> On Error and change the value from “Error Inspector” to “Break in Code”.

To keep the the debugger from being invoked whenever any error anywhere happens, RStudio does not invoke the debugger if it looks like none of your own code is on the stack. If you find that this is excluding an error you want to catch, go to Tools -> Global Options and uncheck “Use debug error handler only when my code contains errors”.

If you really want to invoke the debugger on every error, always, this will do the job:

```
> options(error = browser)
```

This overrides RStudio’s error handler settings. Trapping every error will quickly become annoying, though, so be sure to use the Debug menu to change the error option back when you’re done troubleshooting (or turn off error handling entirely with options(error = NULL)

You can find the source of this text here: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200713843